# Selenium Webdriver: Target url is not well formed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have stored the URL in the excel file. I read the excel file and put the url in the java Properties. i retrieve the url from properties and try to launch it, but i get the error "Target URL  http://demo.guru99.com/V4/ is not well-formed." Please help.

```
Properties pInputOutPut= new Properties();
//here i have code to read the excel file and load the url to properties 
_driver.get(pInputOutPut.getProperty("Url"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved by itself!!. I tried a couple of different urls it worked, then i switched back to my original url it worked too.

Answer (score 1):

I had it resolved by appending (http/https) prefixes to my URL which were missing when I encountered this error. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there aren't some special characters in your string that aren't visible? Microsoft products tend to add more than what is desired